# OJDBC Driver compatible with Oracle 10g and Java 1.8

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g

I am having a rather trivial question. In our project we are using Oracle 10g as the database and Java 1.8 as the language. Can anyone please suggest me which JDBC driver will be suitable in this case?

In the Oracle documentation in the below link:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-10201-088211.html
I found that ojdbc14.jar should be used. However it is written that it is classes compiled using JDK 1.4 and 1.5. So should I use the same driver when using JDK 1.8?

Comment: Please note that ojdbc14 is not a version, it indicates the driver is for Java 1.4. Technically (according to their [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02)), Oracle no longer supports Oracle 10 (unless you pay them a lot of money), but I know from older versions of that FAQ (check archive.org) that the JDBC 11.2 drivers supported Oracle 9.0.1 and higher, and JDBC 12.1 supported at least Oracle 10.2.0 and higher. This could suggest that even JDBC 12.2 might work with Oracle 10.

Comment: However asking for library recommendations is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `ojdbc14.jar` however it won't support methods introduced in JDBC 4 (Java 6), JDBC 4.1 (Java 7) and JDBC 4.2 (Java 8). Because Java emphasizes backwards compatibility you most likely will be able to open the database connection, however:

1. The code will throw [`LinkageError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/LinkageError.html) in runtime if you use methods introduced in JDBC 4+. The code will compile with JDBC 4.2 (Java 8) but these methods will not be available during runtime.
2. You may experience weird behavior with low level features e.g. statement caching and row fetching was modified in 11g `ojdbc6.jar` few times. I'm not even sure how this features work in the old `ojdbc14.jar`.

It's a very unusual, an I'd say not advisable, setup that you want to test. The only way to see if it works is to try it.